# Should we necessarily specify the width of an element to use margin auto?

Tags: html, css

When i use just margin: auto for an element, it doesn't get centered, but when i add for the width a value it just get in the middle.

Comment: How would you propose to equally centre something you don't know the width of? ;) Elements will be full width by default unless specified

Comment: SHow example code

Comment: <style>
h1 {
  margin: auto;
}
</style>
<body>
  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
</body>

Comment: use text-align: center in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a width because by default the block-level elements such as a div, p, list, etc take up the full width of its parent element, and no space is left to adjust the element horizontally. So, the very first thing you need to check is whether you have set the width of the element for margin: auto to work.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a width to an element defines how much space (the margin) will be applied to the element. Different widths will have different `margin: auto` values.

Comment: @lunatic. Yeah you are right, the other answer talking about block-level elements is correct as there is a default width.